# Generate entities for 1:1 relationship without PK on the related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, database-first

I have three tables in existing sql db:

- Events

  - ConcreteEvents1
  - ConcreteEvents2

There is 1:1 relationship between events and concrete events and only events table has PrimaryKey.

Is there any way to scaffold entities from this database?

Unfortunately, I don't own the db

Comment: What exactly do you mean by scaffold entities? generate code based on database structure?

Comment: You can use cat factory and mock a database: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160615/Generating-Code-for-EF-Core-with-CatFactory

Comment: Yes. I think the cli command is called scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: It will not scaffold the entities properly since Concrete tables don't have PK defined. EntityType needs PK defined.